# Как вывести в одном url две модели?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, blade

Есть макет и в нем `sidebar` и `main`. Создал две модели с миграциями: `Sidebar` и `Main` и, соответственно, две таблицы.

Роут:

```
Route::get('/', 'ContentController@main');
```

Получил `content` для `main`:

```
public function main(Request $request) {
        $mains = Main::all();
        return view('index_hub', ['mains'=>$mains]);
```

и вставил в макет `main`.

Вопрос: как вставить в макет `sidebar` из модели (таблицы) `Sidebar`, ведь роут `'/'` (т.е один и тот же)?

p.s. попробовал создать контроллер `Route::get('/', 'ContentController@sidebar');`, но выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

Что мешает сделать так?

```
public function main(Request $request) {
    $mains = Main::all();
    $sidebar = Sidebar::all(); 
    return view('index_hub', ['mains'=>$mains, 'sidebar' => $sidebar]);
```